# simplified into asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

I have a function that needs to be represented in theta form.
The below is my answer.
But the correct answer is **(n.2^n)**

Can someone please explain me how??

[image]

Comment: You are not allowed to take the log of it just because you want to.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove essential content.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\log=\log_2$, we have
$$2^{n+\log_2 n}=2^n \cdot 2^{\log_2 n}=n \cdot 2^n$$
where we used main property(or definition) of $\log$: $a^{\log_a b}=b$, for appropriate $a,b$.